# Initializing sklearn Scaler without fitting

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Is it possible to initialize a scikit-learn StandardScaler without fitting? I know the mean and the variance, but when I set them manually (mean_ and var_), Scaler still does not work until fitted.

It is not that hard to write own scaler and I will go probably this way. I have mean and variance saved from previous data and need to scale new data the same way. I know, it is possible to save the scaler, but it is easier to save the mean and the variance.

Comment: If you already know the mean and the variance of your data, why do you want to use a scaler? Just remove the mean and divide by the variance.

Comment: Well, why use the scaler at all, if you have np.mean and np.var? Isn't it more readable to use scaler.transform(data) and scaler.inverse_transform(scaled_data), than do it manually?

Comment: You can wrap this in your own simple function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to initialize StandardScaler without fitting.

Apart from `mean_` and `var_`, the `scale_` attribute has to be set. It is set to `np.sqrt(self.var_)` via function `_handle_zeros_in_scale` which takes care of that we will not scale by zeros.